# Unaligned first columns with column-count

Tags: html, css, html-lists

In the following I would like to configure the number of columns used to display my list. I noticed the first column is not aligned with the others. Is this normal? What I am missing?

Note that I cannot directly modify the style of `ul`. It has to be on an outside element.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div style="-webkit-column-count: 4;-moz-column-count: 4; column-count: 4;">
        <ul>
            <li>Gods</li>
            <li>Óðinn</li>
            <li>Baldur</li>
            <li>Njörður</li>
            <li>Freyr</li>
            <li>Týr</li>
            <li>Bragi</li>
            <li>Heimdal</li>
            <li>Thor</li>
            <li>Höðr</li>
            <li>Víðar</li>
            <li>Áli or Váli</li>
            <li>Ullr</li>
            <li>Forseti</li>
            <li>Óðinn</li>
            <li>Þór</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must remove the default margin from the unordered list.

```html
<ul style="margin: 0">
```

Default formatting exists in web browsers to make very basic pages more readable. However, it can cause a website to look inconsistent across different browsers. Problems like this are resolved by using a CSS reset stylesheet, such as the meyerweb reset stylesheet, to clear default values for everything.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot edit the `ul` you can add an extra element to cancel the margin

```css
.box {
  column-count: 4;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  margin-top:-1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" >
  <ul>
    <li>Gods</li>
    <li>Óðinn</li>
    <li>Baldur</li>
    <li>Njörður</li>
    <li>Freyr</li>
    <li>Týr</li>
    <li>Bragi</li>
    <li>Heimdal</li>
    <li>Thor</li>
    <li>Höðr</li>
    <li>Víðar</li>
    <li>Áli or Váli</li>
    <li>Ullr</li>
    <li>Forseti</li>
    <li>Óðinn</li>
    <li>Þór</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```